# Pick the latest ECR image which is not tagged latest

Tags: bash, jq, aws-cli

I need to be able to pick the latest tagged image in a ECR repository which does not have the tag latest.

I am trying to achieve this through aws cli and bash/jq

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name <repo-name> --region us-east-1 --output text --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[*]' | tr '\t' '\n' | tail -2
```

The `imageTag` output here is

```
ajohn-feature-123
bgates-feature-345
```

The list may contain `latest` as one of the entries. I want to skip that entry and pick the first imageTag here which is not latest.

Appreciate any help in achieving this.

Comment: What is the question regarding `jq` here? I see no JSON

Comment: There is no direct connection to jq. But I am open to solutions using jq to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are looking to look for the next entry in the output after latest, since you already have the output at text you can pipe the output through to sed and so:

```
aws ecr .... | sed -n '/latest/{n;p}'
```

Search the output of the aws cli command and search for the string latest. When finding this string, skip to the next line of output and print

With awk, taking account of multiple latest tags one after the other

```
aws ecr .... | awk '/latest/ { getline;while ($0=="latest") { getline } print $0 }'
```

Pattern match lines in the output against latest and then run a while loop that moves to the next line if another instance of the string latest is encountered.

```
aws ecr .... | awk '/latest/&&cnt<1 { getline;while ($0=="latest") { getline } print $0;cnt++ } { arr[NR]=$0 } END { if (cnt=="") { print arr[1] } }'
```

Another variation of awk using cnt to ensure that only the first instance found is printed (in case there are multiple latest tags with one not after the other)
An array arr is also created containing each line. If no latest tags are found, the first tag is printed.

Comment: This is certainly a reasonable solution, but what if there is more than one entry containing the "latest" string?  E.g., what if there are two consecutive occurrences of that string?  In contexts where these considerations are relevant, it might be easier to use `awk`.

Comment: Thank you for responding Raman. I tried the `sed` command and it fails with `sed: 1: "/latest/{n;p}": extra characters at the end of p command` . The `awk` solutions do not return anything if both of the the aws cli output is non latest.

Comment: I've amended the last awk solution. Not sure of the the first tag or the last tag should be printed if there are no cases of latest. I have printed the first in my solution, if you need the last then change print arr[1] to print arr[NR]

Comment: That worked. but what was wrong with the `sed`. Is this not possible with `sed`?

Comment: The awk seems to break. not working in all the scenarios

Comment: More clearly, it does not work when latest is the second element in the output. It only works when `latest` is the first element